# Production ready substrate chain

Tags: substrate-node-template

Currently i am using `substrate-node-template` and I have done all my work in that I want to make it production ready, Can someone tell me is there any guide that what changes I have to make in the template node to make it my own chain and how can i deploy it as my own blockchain so it is ready for anyone to connect with it and deploy contracts on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first resource I'd go is the [Network Maintainers](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-index) section in the Polkadot wiki, where you have guides to set up the validators, nodes...

I want to share with you previous questions on StackExchange about this topic:

- [Solo Substrate chains - are there any examples yet?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1517/solo-substrate-chains-are-there-any-examples-yet).
- [How to deploy a hardened, secure, production-ready Substrate node?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/how-to-deploy-a-hardened-secure-production-ready-substrate-node?rq=1)
- [How we can go live as solochain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/how-we-can-go-live-as-solochain/)

Also, if you want the smart contract functionality on top of the `substrate-node-template`, you have been using you have to add the [Pallet Contracts](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts) or the EVM pallets if you want to allow the deployment of EVM smart contracts (Solidity).
You can take a look in these templates:

- [Substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node), for a node with the pallet contracts.
- [Frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier), a template with EVM.

Comment: Hey thanks Alex so i have already configured the pallet contract node in my node template and i will be going with the aura consensus just wanna know now that which parts need to be changed in the node template of substrate in order to make the chain mine and i can interact and can deploy smart contracts on it

Comment: You want to run your chain as a solo chain, that means is up to you the security and everything. In case you want to connect to polkadot to  benefit from the pooled security, thought-through governance, and overall scalability of the heterogeneous sharding approach of the network you need to convert your node into a parachain

Comment: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-pdk

Answer (score 0):

You first need to decide what consensus you want to use for block production [babe](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/glossary/#blind-assignment-of-blockchain-extension-babe) or [aura](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/glossary/#authority-round-aura), as `node-template` use aura and [substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) uses babe.

You must be familiar with how to set a [private network](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/simulate-network/) you just need to set up the network on any cloud service like `AWS`, there is no specific guide on how to launch a production ready chain. You can follow [this](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-bootnode) if it helps.